# Select dataset rows that meet a mathematical criterion in a column

Tags: filtering, dataset, query

Here is a simple dataset:

```
data = Dataset[<|"Joe" -> <|"Day" -> "Mon", "Rate" -> 11|>, 
   "Sue" -> <|"Day" -> "Tue", "Rate" -> 13|>, 
   "Paul" -> <|"Day" -> "Wed", "Rate" -> 10|>, 
   "Leslie" -> <|"Day" -> "Thurs", "Rate" -> 15|>, 
   "Sam" -> <|"Day" -> "Fri", "Rate" -> 9|>|>]
```

I'd like to select the rows where, for example, 10<="Rate"<=14 and then total those amounts. I've tried various methods using, for example, Select, but I can't find anything that Mathematica will accept.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you intend to use a `Dataset` with named rows (and being aware that this means that each row must have a unique name), one way is:

```
(*define the dataset*)
data = Dataset[<|"Sue" -> <|"Day" -> "Tue", "Rate" -> 13|>, 
   "Paul" -> <|"Day" -> "Wed", "Rate" -> 10|>, 
   "Leslie" -> <|"Day" -> "Thurs", "Rate" -> 15|>, 
   "Sam" -> <|"Day" -> "Fri", "Rate" -> 9|>|>]

(*illustrative example:  just applying the operation and return only the Rate column*)
data[Select[10 <= #["Rate"] <= 14 &], "Rate"] 


(*Answer to the question: apply the operation and return only the total*)
data[Select[10 <= #["Rate"] <= 14 &], "Rate"][Total]
```

Alternatively, you can also define your search as a `Query`, and try something like:

```
selectQ = Query[Select[10 <= #Rate <= 14 &], "Rate"];
Total@selectQ[data]
```

(note that either `#["Rate"]` or `#Rate` can be used to denote the named column.)

--Edit--

As J. M.'s ennui pointed out in the comments, there is also the ability to apply `Total` using a right-composition (`/*`).  This allows you to incorporate the `Total` operation into the `Query`, like follows:

```
totalQ = Query[Select[10 <= #Rate <= 14 &] /* Total, "Rate"];
totalQ[data]
```

(You are also free to use the `Between` function in any of these, as demonstrated in J.M.'s comment, if that seems more natural.)

Comment: I tend to prefer using `Between[]` for situations like this: `data[Select[Between[#Rate, {10, 14}] &] /* Total, "Rate"]`

Comment: `Between` is rather slick, and I learned something about the use of the right-composition `\*`

Answer (score 0):

A simple and feasible method:

```
data = Dataset[{"Sue" -> <|"Day" -> "Tue", "Rate" -> 13|>, 
   "Paul" -> <|"Day" -> "Wed", "Rate" -> 10|>, 
   "Leslie" -> <|"Day" -> "Thurs", "Rate" -> 15|>, 
   "Sam" -> <|"Day" -> "Fri", "Rate" -> 9|>}]
Cases[data, 
  HoldPattern[_ -> Association[__, "Rate" -> x_]] /; 10 <= x <= 14 :> 
   List[x]] // Total
```

Comment: Your dataset is a bit broken; I believe OP wanted the "named row" form, so it should be an association with keys Sue, Paul, etc. rather than a list of rules.

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier +1 Thank you. I think your understanding is correct.